# SignalR server certificate validate in client application

Tags: c#, signalr, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, signalr.client

**Signal-R server certificate validate in client application**

I wrote below code and made certificate.I am validating server certification but How can i tell to Signal-R Server  Thats required certificate

Currently weather i have certificate or not i can access Signalr server

*Client app web.config*

```
  <location path="signalr">
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <access sslFlags="SslRequireCert" />
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

*Client app c# code*

```
  HubConnection connection = new HubConnection(ServiceUri,false);
  connection.AddClientCertificate(X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("cer509.cer"));
 IHubProxy proxy = connection.CreateHubProxy("myHub");
 connection.Start().Wait();
```